# Call a function with optional parameter with default value?

Tags: python

I need to call the following function.

```
def f(p):
    # .....
    g(p)
```

and `p` of `g(p)` is optional

```
def g(p=some_default_value):
```

I actually need `f(p)` to call `g()` without `p` (I don't know `some_default_value` and it may change). However, `p` of `f(p)` is required. Is it a way to set `p` to some special value to let `f` call `g` with the default value of `p`?

```
f(p=..?..)
```

Comment: There is no such special value. You'd have to write two conditional calls: `if p is None:` / `g()` / `else:` / `g(p)`  (choose a different default value for `p` if None is a valid value for it).

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
def g(p=None):
    pass

def f(p):
    g()
```

As long as you don't pass in `p` in `g()`, it is not taking anything in.